# Metamask keeps rotating the loader when I call Approve() method of token in web3

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js

I'm an entry-level blockchain developer, so I often get stuck, but the community here is always there to help with the already asked questions, but this time I couldn't get what I need.
What I'm actually trying to accomplish is that I have deployed my ERC20 token smart contract on Ganache, and trying to call the approve function of that contract in my web3 project so users can approve some tokens to be transferred. It's working fine on the remix. but not able to call it from web3. Below is the code line I have written
`this.state.token.methods.approve(address, '100000000000000000000').send({from:this.state.account})`

When I click the button metamask pops up for confirmation but the loader just keeps loading.

Comment: I am having this exact same issue, honestly looks like a metamask bug...

Comment: I tried on metamask mobile, it works fine...

Comment: Update: it is a metamask bug!
https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/14522